# PythonScript won't run from folder but runs from terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to VSCode and Python, and I'm trying to get a grasp of how VSCode works with Path variables. I have two versions of Python installed and a virtual environment:

I also have a relatively simple script saved in a folder (standardplot.py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x)) 
plt.show()
```

When I select the virtual environment I can run the script just fine by using the Run Python file in terminal button in VScode. however, changing to the "normal" environment and running again gives a can't find matplot lib module error. Matplotlib is installed in both virtual and normal environment. If I run the file from a powershell terminal as 
`python standardplot.py`
also works.

I'm not sure why the script won't run if I just run it in VSCode.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem relating to VS Code configuration. Checking these documentations may help:

Python environments: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Getting Started with Python in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter

Python in Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: thanks for the reply! I actually figured it out. I never installed python 3.8.2 with the environment variables, but I had installed a windowsapp version of python 3.8 (from VScode). I uninstalled that app, modified the regular python to add the PATH variables and works now.